# Windows 7 as a media box - is there a way to stop kids leaving Media Player without a password?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-media-player

In the TV room we have a Windows 7 professional box as a media centre for the family. My daughter has just turned five and increased her confidence. I'd like to lock down Windows Media player so you can't leave it without a password.

My question is, with **Windows 7 as a media box - is there a way to stop kids leaving Media player without a password?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a new account for just Media Player, and using Windows Family Safety, lock it down so that the user can do nothing but open Media Player.

When you need to, you can just switch users and have a password on your account.